# Finding an MST with one adding and removing vertex operation

Tags: graphs, trees, minimum-spanning-tree

I am facing the following problem: Given an **undirected complete Euclidean weighted** graph $G(V, E)$ and its **MST** $T$. I need to **remove** an arbitrary vertex $v_i \in V(G)$, and given a vertex $v_j \notin V(G)$, I have to calculate the MST of $$G^{'}((V(G) \backslash \{v_i\})\cup\{v_j\}, (E\backslash\{(v_i, v_k): v_k \in V(G)\})\cup\{(v_k, v_j): v_k \in V(G^{'})\}),$$ i.e, the graph $G$ with the vertex $v_j$ (and edges from $v_j$ to every other vertex) and without the vertex $v_i$ (and its respective edges). To solve this, we can apply some well-known MST algorithms, such as Prim's, Kruskal's, Borukva's algorithm. Neverthless, if we do this we would not use the already existing MST $T$, i.e., we would calculate a new whole MST. So, I would like to know if there is any way to reuse the existing MST $T$.

There are two similar questions to this [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/124363/is-the-subgraph-of-a-mst-an-mst-of-the-subgraph-that-its-vertices-represent) (with edges, considering only the removing of them), and [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/56486/finding-mst-after-adding-a-new-vertex) (with vertex, considering only the adding of them).

The vertices are points in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the weight on each edge is the Euclidean distance between the two points.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/124369/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91539/755, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/56486/755.

Comment: Why would the new MST necessarily share a single edge with what's left of the previous one after removing $v_i$? Consider $V = \{(0,0),(0,3),(4,0)\}$ and replace $(4,0)$ with $(0,1)$.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get your point.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long hours facing this problem, with my advisor help, we could solve this problem in $O(|E(G^{'})| log\text{ }C)$ time complexity by using one iteration of the [Boruvka's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bor%C5%AFvka%27s_algorithm), where $C$ is the number of connected components of $G^{''} (V(G^{'}), T\backslash \{(v_k, v_i): v_k \in V(G^{'})\})$, i.e., the number of connected components of the MST $T$ by removing $v_i$ (and edges from $v_i$ to every other vertex in $T$) plus one (due to the inserted vertex $v_j$).

Note that, this solution might have $O(|E(G^{'})| log\text{ }|V(G^{'})|)$ time complexity if the removing of $v_i$ in $T$ (and edges from $v_i$ to every other vertex in $T$) lead to a totally disconnected graph. Also, note that, this solution has $\Omega(|E(G^{'})|)$ if C is equals to 3.